# Ajax no envia peticion php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tengo un par de formularios en una misma pagina, e inserto el script ajax desde un archivo externo llamado scripts.

En dicho archivo se procesan dos formularios

```
/*===================================*
16. PROCESS LOGIN FORM
*===================================*/
 $('#btn-redirect').hide();

$(document).ready(function(){
//var wpm = $("#wrong_pass_modal");
//var num = $("#no_user_modal");
//var md = $("#loading_modal");
$('.FormLogin').on("submit", function(event){
event.preventDefault(); 
$.ajax({
url:".ingreso.php",  
method:"POST",  
data:$('#FormLogin').serialize(), 
dataType: 'json', 
success:function(response){
     if(response.status){
        switch(response.status){


          //case 'PASSWORD':
          //wpm.modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});
          //wpm.modal('show');
          //break;

          //case 'NOEXISTE':
          //  num.modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});
          //  num.modal('show');
          //  break;


           case 'EXISTE':
           //  md.modal('show');  
             //$('#login_form')[0].reset();  
             window.location=("index2.php");
             break;
           }
         }
} 
  });  
 });   
})




/*===================================*
17. PROCESS CONTACT FORM
*===================================*/

//contenido original del botn para guardar. para restaurarlo luego de las animaciones
$('#sending').hide();

   //funcion q maneja el envio de la informacion
$('#contact-form').on('submit',function(e){
  $('#sending').show();
  $('#submit').hide();

  //evita q se envia automaticamente, oculta el alert si esta expuesto y anima el boton
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = $(this);
  //funcion de espera para hacer la consulta de ajax
  setTimeout(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: './resources/contacto.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: form.serialize(),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response){
        if(response.success===true){
          $('#contact-form').trigger("reset");
          $('.alert-msg').html('Thanks for contacting us!, One member of our team will contact you shortly ');
          $('#sending').hide();
          $('#submit').show();
        }
        if(response.success===false){
          $('#contact-form').trigger("reset");
          $('.message').html('Sorry, there is an error in the form');
          boton.show();
        } 
      },
      error: function(){

        $('.message').html('Thanks for contacting us!, One member of our team will contact you shortly ');  //llena el mensaje del alerta
        alert.fadeIn();                             //muestra el alerta 
        boton.html(btnContent).prop('disabled',false);              //reestablece el boton
      }
    });
},1000);
});
```

El caso es que cuando se procesa el formulario, se presentan los distintos problemas:

- Al hacer click al procesar login, algunas veces no hace nada, otras veces se visualiza en el navegador el paso de las variables = pagina.php?variable=1&variable=2... y esto es a pesar de que en ninguna parte hay un get de por medio
- Cuando elimino el event.preventdefault para que camine la app, el formulario que procesa es el de contacto.

Solo me pasa en este sitio. He programado un sitio con varios modal, y se ejecutan sin problema las peticiones ajax, quisiera saber que estoy haciendo mal para poder corregirlo.

Comment: Revisa si tus dos formularios tienen definida las class="FormLogin"

Comment: Los dos estan definidas y delimitadas. Ahora estoy probando con otro script y me sigue enviando la peticion a donde no es, pasando variable por el navegador

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el html?